# Please suggest an approach to unit testing a simple function

Tags: unit-testing

Suppose I have the following function (pseudocode):

```
bool checkObjects(a, b)
{
    if ((a.isValid() && (a.hasValue()) || 
        (b.isValid() && (b.hasValue()))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Which tests should I write to be able to claim that it's 100% covered?

There are total 16 possible input combinations. Should I write 16 test cases, or should I try to act smart and omit some test cases?

For example, should I write test for

```
[a valid and has value, b valid and has value]
```

if I tested that it returns what expected for

```
[a valid and has value, b invalid and has value]
```

and

```
[a invalid and has value, b valid and has value]
```

?

Thanks!

P.S.: Maybe someone can suggest good reading on unit testing approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Driven Development by Kent Beck is well-done and is becoming a classic (http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-Development-Kent-Beck/dp/0321146530)

If you wanted to be thorough to the max then yes 16 checks would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Speaking personally, I'd be satisfied to test all boundary conditions.  So both cases where it is true, but making one item false would make the overall result false, and all 4 false cases where making one item true would make the overall result true.  But that is a judgment call, and I wouldn't fault someone who did all 16 cases.

Incidentally if you unit tested one true case and one false one, code coverage tools would say that you have 100% coverage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are woried about writing 16 test cases, you can try some features like [NUnit TestCase](http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5) or [MbUnit RowTest](http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5). Other languages/frameworks should have similar features.

This would allow you to test all 16 conditions with a single (and small) test case).

Answer (score 1):

If testing seems hard, think about refactoring. I can see several approaches here. First merge `isValid()` and `hasValue()` into one method and test it separately. And why have `checkObjects(a, b)` testing two unrelated objects? Why can't you have `checkObject(a)` and `checkObject(b)`, decreasing the exponential growth of possibilities further? Just a hint.

If you really want to test all 16 possibilities, consider some more table-ish tools, like Fitnesse (see http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitTableStyles). Also check [Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) JUnit runner and TestNG.